# Unable to automate "click on OK button" with UIAutomation

Tags: javascript, ios, uibutton, ios-ui-automation

This is the 3d View the `UIHieracrchy` is as follows

```
APP -> UIWindow -> UILayoutContainerView -> UINavigationTransitionView -> UIViewControllerWrapperView->UIView->UIButton
```

(`UIButton` in detail)

```
UIButton -> UIImageView -> MyButton ->UIButtonLabel
```

SO I tried the following

1. ```
   UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert)
   {
       var title = alert.name();
       if(title == "Failed" || title == "Warning")
       {
           target.delay(5);  
           alert.buttons()["OK"].tap();
           return true;
       }
       UIALogger.logPass("Sign In Failed");
       return false;
   }
   ```

   2. `target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["OK"].tap();`
   3. `target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()[0].tap();`

   Please help me resolve this issue of automating this button.

Comment: Can you post more of the code that you're using, specifically the code that gets you from `UIALogger.logStart` to the alert handler?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've commented out the line where you actually dismiss the alert:

```
    //alert.buttons()["OK"].tap();
```

This means that the button cannot be reached by UIAutomation -- the alert is still blocking it.

In some instances, there is also a bug where an alert popup will alter the value of `target`, and you have to re-initialize it.

Comment: Sorry thats my bad although I tried without commenting while asking the question I commented that out so I edited the question please have a look and thank you :)

Comment: My guess is that you're confusing the `onAlert` function (which only handles OS-level popups, such as those asking for permission to use the location) with your own popup (referred to by `target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["OK"].tap();`).  It's difficult to know for sure based on the limited code you've posted in your question.